# Something signed me up for rather spammy insecure alerts from routerlogin.dev need to stop it

Tags: windows, alerts

I get an abundance of fake alerts from a very suspicious "routerLogin.dev" and I don't know how to stop them. They are trying to get me to install malware.

I've tried installing fiddler to determine where they are coming from, but I can't find it in the clutter.

They have messages like "WIN: system files damaged" or "Personal Offer to You" so on and on.

I have installed Malwarebytes and it doesn't stop the spamming but it does recognize that the links if I click on them are malware.

I have not installed anything insecure on this computer, I'm a dev and I'm hep to that.

Answer (score 0):

This irritating hack comes if you accidentally just visit routerlogin.dev instead of routerlogin.net.

It somehow gets permission to start messaging you. I found this on reddit:

```
chrome: Settings | Privacy and Security | Site Settings
```

RouterLogin.dev was listed, and then you can click on it and block everything.